Why the fonts of my project are applied in Development Stage, but not in Production, project made in NextJS
I'm making a test product and I've already finished the ui with the surprise that when I deploy it to production it doesn't have Google Fonts applied, it's worth emphasizing that I'm using the import method for the fonts, I share the project's repository 
git repo:https://github.com/Thewoker/NextJs/tree/main/gym-ecommerce
I didn't really try many alternatives, right now I'm trying to implement the fonts no longer by importing from Google Fonts but from a local file with the fonts already downloaded

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

While going through your repo, in app/layout.js you have created a inter variable but haven't used it anywhere.
Going through the official docs, you should add it to className of high level parent tag i.e. html or body.
<body className={inter.className}>

Though I am not able to guess why is it working at developmental stage.
